# How to create an automated presentation showing determined graphics

Tags: beamer, xifthen

I am a maths teacher trying to make an automated slide to use as students come into my class. The aim is to revisit topics that we have learnt previously and I am taking photos of questions at the end of each lesson and saving them as the lesson number. I want to create a beamer document which on each slide shows the questions from the previous lesson, 3 lessons before, 6 and 12 lessons before.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\foreach \Lesson in {13,...,15}
{ \IfFileExists{\Lesson.jpg}
    {\begin{frame}{Starter}
        \begin{table}[h!]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
                \hline
                Last Lesson & Last Week\\
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\LastLesson.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                &
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\LastWeek.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                \\ \hline
                Last Fortnight & Last Month\\
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\LastFortnight.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                &
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\LastMonth.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table} 
    \end{frame}
    }{
    }
}
\end{document}
```

My question is how do I define \LastLesson, \LastWeek, \LastFortnight and \LastMonth based on the value that \Lesson is taking? That is:

\LastLesson = \Lesson -1

\LastWeek = \Lesson -3

\LastFortnight = \Lesson -6

\LastMonth = \Lesson -12

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load `pgffor` since you are using `\foreach`, and you can use `\numexpr` to subtract integers from other integers, see the code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\foreach \Lesson in {13,...,15}
{ \IfFileExists{\Lesson.jpg}
    {\begin{frame}{Starter}
        \begin{table}[h!]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
                \hline
                Last Lesson & Last Week\\
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\the\numexpr\Lesson-1\relax.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                &
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\the\numexpr\Lesson-3\relax.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                \\ \hline
                Last Fortnight & Last Month\\
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\the\numexpr\Lesson-6\relax.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                &
                \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\the\numexpr\Lesson-12\relax.jpg}
                \end{minipage}
                \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table} 
    \end{frame}
    }{
    }
}
\end{document}
```